# Delphi 10.2 crashing on startup: where are "recent projects" stored?

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo

I think that I opened a bad Project, and now every time I open Delphi 10.2, it crashes.  Where is the list of Projects stored, so that I can remove the bad Project from the list?  Thanks!

Comment: The startup splash screen shows, then I see the message "The notification platform is unavailable" two times, then I see the message "Access violation at address 50067898 in module 'rtl250.bpl'.  Read of address 219D57E0"

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the root directory in which I store all of my Delphi source code for all Projects, so that Delphi could not find the offending Project which was causing the crash.  After Delphi started up correctly, but without opening a Project, I opened a valid Project and quit.  I then renamed the root directory.  Things are working again.